# Ignore directories/files in Cmd-T opener in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to open files using `Cmd+T` on Sublime Text. I'm sure I remember it taking it's settings from the "find in project" bottom bar (`Cmd+^+F`), but that doesn't seem to work.

To clarify, my find in project settings include `-node_modules/` and when searching for strings I know are in files in that folder, it doesn't find them, but when I try to open `readme.md` using `Cmd+T`, it shows me all the readmes in my modules.